# NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_protocol_version' for #<App:0x007fcc0cb32010>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, timestamp, nameerror

I have some problems with my unit test.

When i run my unit test i have some problem with:

1. `timestamp`
2. `undefined loacal variable or method`

========== 1 ============

When i run the unit test, i have an error with `timpestamp` and `date field`. it say:

```
  -      "date"=>"2011-11-05T22:03:54+09:00",
  ?                           ^        ^
  +      "date"=>"2011-11-05T20:03:54+07:00",
  ?                           ^        ^
         "finished"=>1,
         "position"=>"",
         "timestamp"=>"2014-03-21T09:43:05+07:00",
         "type"=>"new type"},
       "content_id2"=>
        {"bookmark_suffix_max"=>3,
         "bookmarks"=>
          [{"date"=>"", "label"=>"", "name"=>"", "position"=>""},
           {"date"=>"", "label"=>"", "name"=>"", "position"=>""}],
  -      "date"=>"2011-11-04T22:03:54+09:00",
  ?                           ^        ^
  +      "date"=>"2011-11-04T20:03:54+07:00",
  ?                           ^        ^
         "finished"=>1,
         "position"=>"",
  -      "timestamp"=>"2011-11-04T22:03:54+09:00",
  ?                                ^        ^
  +      "timestamp"=>"2011-11-04T20:03:54+07:00",
  ?                                ^        ^
         "type"=>""}},
     "timestamp"=>"2014-03-21T09:43:05+07:00"}
test_merge1_with_conflict_1:_should_update_bookmark_info_with_client's_'date'_field(AccountBookmarkInfoTest)
```

Is it because of `time_zone` ? or something else. I already fix the `-` with `+` but i've still have same error with that.

============ 2 ===============

```
Error: test_ContentsJsonCache.key_for_params_should_depend_all_query_parameters(ContentsJsonCacheTest)
  NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_protocol_version' for #<App:0x007fcc0a3f8800>
app/models/app.rb:166:in `implements_purchase_bonus_feature?'
app/models/app.rb:174:in `include_purchase_bonuses_in_contents_json?'
app/models/contents_json_cache.rb:21:in `key_for_params'
test/unit/contents_json_cache_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:ContentsJsonCacheTest>'
```

`current_local_version` is in :

```
**Controller. define : app.current_protocol_version

**Models. define :

    attr_accessible :current_protocol_version,
                    :name,
                    ....
**test->functional->app.controller_test.rb

    app = apps :one
    app.current_protocol_version = '1.1.9'
    assert_false app.implements_account_feature?
```

Comment: Please show your test code.

Comment: if you plz post your code

Comment: i'm sorrfy, i'm afraid to do that..

Comment: the problem already solve, by change `attr_accessible` to `attr_accessor`

Answer (score 0):

## To fix timestamp error do this in your code.

if you have code like this below:

before.

```
time.parse var
```

after

```
time.zone.parse var
```